# How to scan for an input from a jtextfield?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, jtextfield

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Fun {
    @SuppressWarnings({"static-access", "resource"})
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("The Gamer Zone");
        //set size and location of frame
        f.setSize(390, 300);
        f.setLocation(100, 150);
        //make sure it quits when x is clicked
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //set look and feel
        f.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JLabel labelM = new JLabel("Are you an epic gamer? (true,false) ");
        labelM.setBounds(50, 50, 250, 30);
        JTextField Text = new JTextField();
        //set size of the text box
        Text.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 30);
        //add elements to the frame
        f.add(labelM);
        f.add(Text);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        String answer1 = Text.getText();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(answer1);
        int x = 0;
        while (x < 1) {
            try {
                if (sc.next() == "true") {
                    f.remove(labelM);
                    x++;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Something went wrong");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get it to remove `LabelM` when the input in the jtext field is "true." I am just trying to learn how `JFrame`s work, and this is my first time working with one. Is there a better way to scan from a `JFrame`?

Comment: In Java you done use `==` to compare objects rather use `.equals` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java) for more

Comment: `if (sc.next() == "true")` -> [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832)

Comment: Usually, there's a submit JButton on the JPanel.  The submit button lets the application know that the user is finished typing.  The ActionListener of the submit button gets the text from the JTextFields and processes the information.  The Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will take you through all the steps of creating Swing GUIs.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc *Usually, there's a submit JButton on the JPanel* I think thats up to how somebody want to implement their UI as opposed to a rule

Comment: Thank you for all of the help with solving this problem!!

Comment: @ARRONSTANLEY glad to be of help if my answer has solved your problem dont forget to mark it as solved by  checking the tick next to the answer to show others it is solved. Read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a [DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) which will fire off methods whenever the text of the *field* is changed. Currently your example gets the text once (after showing the `JFrame` and that will never change as well as you are using the wrong method/operator to compare `string` objects in java you should use `equals`, or a variant like `contains` etc see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10806192/1133011) for more.

Also some other points (I probably sound like a broken record):

1. Don't use a `null`/`AbsoluteLayout` rather use an appropriate [LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)
2. Don't call `setBounds()` or `setSize()`  on components, if you use a correct layout manager this will be handled for you
3. Call `JFrame#pack()` before setting the frame to visible when using a `LayoutManager`
4. All Swing components should be called on the [EDT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10806192/1133011) via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

Here is an example which simply hides or shows the `JLabel` when the word *true* is found or not found regardless of case in the `JTextField`:

[image]

**TestApp.java:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class TestApp {

    public TestApp() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(TestApp::new);
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestApp");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        JLabel labelM = new JLabel("Are you an epic gamer? (true,false) ");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                checkForInput();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                checkForInput();
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                checkForInput();
            }

            public void checkForInput() {
                if (textField.getText().toLowerCase().equals("true")) {
                    labelM.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    labelM.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });

        panel.add(labelM, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

The magic happens in the `checkForInput` called by the `DocumentListener` which is attached to the `JTextField`

```
public void checkForInput() {
    if (textField.getText().toLowerCase().contains("true")) {
        labelM.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        labelM.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If you wanted to add or remove the label as opposed to setting its visibility simply switch it out with `panel.remove(labelM)` or `panel.add(labelM)` respectively